# WPF: Best way to block OnPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have implemented WPF data binding with INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
  public class ExportNode : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public uint Handle { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }
    private bool _ischecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return _ischecked;
        }
        set
        {
            _ischecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");

        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        } 
    }
}
```

And than subscribing to event form my code, so whenever I change property in UI, it fires callback.
But now I'm trying to figure out the best way to change property from code, and than not fire callback, just update UI.

```
        void newNode_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           if (e.PropertyName == "IsChecked")
           {
           }
        }
```

For now I just thought about implementing some "blocker" member property in ExportNode

```
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (Blocked)
            return;
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        } 
    }
```

or delete event form instance before change.

```
                newNode.PropertyChanged -= newNode_PropertyChanged;
                newNode.IsChecked = true;
                newNode.PropertyChanged += newNode_PropertyChanged;
```

But is there any better way? I just don't understand some basics? :-)

Thank you very much

Roman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got this a *little* backwards.

`INotifyPropertyChanged`, and thus the `PropertyChanged` event, **is** what makes the UI update, in fact, its what makes the whole binding system work.

So to update the UI, you **have** to raise that event. Now, from the code side, you almost *never* subscribe to that event, because you could just invoke a method from the setter. Something like:

```
    set
    {
        _ischecked = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");

        if (!Blocked)
            MyOtherMethod();
    }
```

Note that if you are dealing with threads, that `Blocked` condition is a *major* synchronization hazard.

If you *really* need to register for `PropertyChanged` from code, then your best bet is to just unregister with `-=`. That way the UI still gets its event, but you don't.

Comment: oh, thank you for clarification. I think I should get more sleep :-)